# How to customize login form page?

Tags: 7, forms, users

I am trying to customize the login Form using the following code.

```
$elements  = drupal_get_form("user_login"); 
$form      = drupal_render($elements);
print $form;
```

It render Username, Password field and the log-in button without..

**What's the correct way to render the login form?**

Comment: You can add links through hook_form_alter()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the following code in the *template.php* for your theme. Replace *mytheme* with the effective machine name of that theme.

```php
function mytheme_theme($existing, $type, $theme, $path) {
  return array(
    'user_login' => array(
      'arguments' => array('form' => NULL),
      'render element' => 'form',
      'template' => 'templates/user-login',
    ),
  );
}
```

Then create the *user-login.tpl.php* template file with the following code.

```html
<?php
  print drupal_render($form['name']);
  print drupal_render($form['pass']);
?>
<div class="user-login-links">
  <span class="password-link"><a href="/user/password">Forget your password?</a></span> | <span class="register-link"><a href="/user/register">Create an account</a></span>
</div>

<?php
  print drupal_render($form['form_build_id']);
  print drupal_render($form['form_id']);
  print drupal_render($form['actions']);
?>
```